# Repeat certain line of code every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, repeat

I want to repeat a certain line of code to repeat itself every 3 seconds, here's what I've tried so far:

```
function saveEdits() {
  var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");
  var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
  localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
  document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
}
```

Comment: Hard to believe a web search didn't at least give you a starting point towards solving this yourself

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) which will repeat a function every certain number of milliseconds.